# Make a registry/database list in Java

Tags: java, database, variables, registry

I wonder how to make a registry/database list in Java. I mean if I, for example, have a variable called "data", and then I add a new entry to that called "name" with the value "David". Then I would call something like "data.name" to get the value "David".
[As seen on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Xv1.png)

I've been Googling but not finding anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a Map from String to String. You can use a `HashMap<String,String>` for that.

```
// Create Map using HashMap
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

// Set name
data.put("name", "David");

// Get name
String name = data.get("name");
System.out.println(name);
```